# status command not found in linux

Tags: linux, bash, celery, sh, centos7

I have a `celery.config` file in location `/etc/init/celery.config` and I can run commands like `status celery`, `start celery` and `stop celery`, these commands works as expected in Linux.

But when I put these commands in a shell script service and run `sh service.sh` I got error **status: command not found**

here is my service.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

CELERYD=$(status celery)
echo"$CELERYD"
```

Comment: Are you sure that these commands are Linux executables and not commands to be run from python ?

Comment: First find were the command is stored by 'wich status' and then add it like '/usr/bin/status celery' instead

Comment: @pifor yes these are Linux executables command

Comment: it woud be better if you created celery service

Answer (score 1):

According to the tag - you use CentOS 7. This version of CentOS uses systemd by default so you may consider writing a systemd service script instead. However, for backwards compatibility the old `service` command still works, and if you have appropriate init.d script `service celery status` is the right way to find out information about the `celery` service. The code you presented is far from usable SysV init script. The best is to pick any of the scripts in your /etc/init.d directory (if you have any - as I mentioned CentOS 7 does not use SysV init anymore) and use it as template for celery.

Celery has information about how to use both SysV and systemd in its [Daemonizing](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html) section of its documentation, with links to some examples.